# Get only last messages from database mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the next one:

```
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
| id     | userToId  | userFromId  | message     |   date         |
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  1     |   1       |   2         |  Hi         |06/30/2018/18:00|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  2     |   1       |   2         |  how r u    |06/30/2018/18:01|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  3     |   3       |   5         |  Hi         |06/30/2018/17:00|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  4     |   1       |   5         |  Hi         |06/30/2018/19:00|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  5     |   7       |   1         |  Hi         |06/30/2018/19:00|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
```

And, I want to get only the last messages (send or received) related to a particular user provided his `user ID`. So, for example, if the `user ID` is `1` then the output should look like this:

```
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
| id     | userToId  | userFromId  | message     |   date         |
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  2     |   1       |   2         |  how r u    |06/30/2018/18:01|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  4     |   1       |   5         |  Hi         |06/30/2018/19:00|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  5     |   7       |   1         |  Hi         |06/30/2018/19:00|
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
```

This output means (for user with `id = 1`) that the latest messages received from others users were:

```
"how r u" -> from user with id = 2
"Hi" -> from user with id = 5
```

And the latest messages send to other users were:

```
"Hi" -> to user with id = 7
```

Comment: This is basic SQL. You should try something and then if you have a problem ask for help But just throwing your hands up in the air for something so simple means when stuff gets harder you're really going to be in trouble.

Comment: This is way too basic should have tried

Comment: I don't see this too basic. **First** the date format is not standard, and **second** he need only **latest messages** from each group of users. Ignoring the previous, you should ever provide an example query of what you have tried so far...

Comment: I don't understand the expected output, only message with id 5 is from user 1? Given that I don't understand the question fully I might be wrong but what is so basic about this sql unless it is only `WHERE userFromId = 1` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson For what I understood, he wants to retrieve the latest messages a particular user has received/send from/to others users.

Comment: @Shidersz then why does OP write "...only last messages _from_ one user..."

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think the `from` on that `prhase` is not strictly related to the `userFromId` column, but to the messages that are associated to the particular user (sended or received by it). At leats, that is what one can assume from the expected output. Anyways, I think he/she don't want to put efforts on clarificate his question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, I suggest to use normalized date formats (read [Date Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)) on the database and convert it on the query if you want to show in another format. Now, for your particular case and the `datetime` format you use on the table, I will go with the next query:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    msgs AS m
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT
          userToId,
          userFromId,
          MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y/%H:%i')) AS maxDate
      FROM
          msgs
      GROUP BY
          userToId, userFromId
     ) AS l ON l.userToId = m.userToId
            AND l.userFromId = m.userFromId
            AND l.maxDate = STR_TO_DATE(m.`date`, '%m/%d/%Y/%H:%i')
WHERE
    m.userToId = <your_user_id> OR m.userFromId = <your_user_id>;
```

You can check online example with some data here:

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fDGdofzpKPV58ZE4xTepo/3)

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: Thanks for answer but actually I need to provide userId

Comment: @JohnConde Why is off-topic question? Should then I delete my answer? I tooks me 30 minutes of my life trying to help here.

Comment: @Ngssa, just add a `where` clause at the end for filter the `userId`. I'm going to update with this...

Comment: @Shidersz Thank you verry much. This help me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLEHJ1EgNT9zjecYZEnCcb/0

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
LEFT JOIN my_table temp
ON t.userToId = temp.userToId
   AND t.userFromId = temp.userFromId
   AND t.date < temp.date
WHERE (t.userToId = 1
       OR t.userFromId = 1)
       AND temp.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)